# Hyperlink Button and Json Uri

Tags: c#, json, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

in my UWP application i'm parsing text image and URI from Json file, but when i parse the URI and call for it in my xaml page in a hyperlink button nothing happen. please if any one can check with me this code and tell maybe if i should convert the string to uri (Common_sense_media,metacritic) or the inverse or tell me what to do to make it work

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        jsonCall();
    }



    public static BitmapImage ImageFromRelativePath(FrameworkElement parent, string path)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(parent.BaseUri, path);
        BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
        result.UriSource = uri;
        return result;
    }





    public async void jsonCall()
    {
        List<Result> listResult = new List<Result>();

        var client = new HttpClient();
        String jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://api-public.guidebox.com/v1.43/Tunisia/rKgEWJbFg0kgEHrcGXPKhPDo0XtTafyC/movies/all/250/250"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(JsonValue.Parse(jsonString).ValueType);
        JsonObject root = JsonValue.Parse(jsonString).GetObject();
        JsonArray res = root.GetNamedArray("results");

        for (uint i = 0; i < res.Count; i++)
        {
            JsonObject con = res.GetObjectAt(i);
            String id = con.GetNamedNumber("id").ToString();
            String title = con.GetNamedString("title");
            string release_year = con.GetNamedNumber("release_year").ToString();
            string themoviedb = con.GetNamedNumber("themoviedb").ToString();
            string original_title = con.GetNamedString("original_title");
            JsonArray alt = con.GetNamedArray("alternate_titles");
            String name = "-";
            if (alt.Count != 0) { 
            name = alt.GetStringAt(0);
            for (uint j = 1; j < alt.Count; j++)
            {
                name = name + ", " + alt.GetStringAt(j);
            }
            }
            string imdb = con.GetNamedString("imdb");
            string pre_order = con.GetNamedBoolean("pre_order").ToString();
            string in_theaters = con.GetNamedBoolean("in_theaters").ToString();
            string release_date = con.GetNamedString("release_date");
            string rating = con.GetNamedString("rating");
            string rottentomatoes = con.GetNamedNumber("rottentomatoes").ToString();
            string freebase = con.GetNamedString("freebase");
            string wikipedia_id = con.GetNamedNumber("wikipedia_id").ToString();
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("------------------------------"+con.GetNamedValue("metacritic").ValueType);

            // string metacritic = con.GetNamedString("metacritic");
            //     MediaElement metacritic= VideoFromRelativePath(this, con.GetNamedValue("metacritic").ValueType.ToString());
            string common_sense_media = con.GetNamedValue("common_sense_media").ToString();
            string metacritic = con.GetNamedValue("metacritic").ToString();

           // Uri Common_sense_media = con.GetNamedValue("Common_sense_media").ToString();
            //   string Common_sense_media = con.GetNamedValue("Common_sense_media").ToString();
            //string Common_sense_media = con.GetNamedString("metacritic");
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-------------"+Common_sense_media);
            BitmapImage Poster_120x171 = ImageFromRelativePath(this, con.GetNamedString("poster_120x171"));
            BitmapImage poster_240x342 = ImageFromRelativePath(this, con.GetNamedString("poster_240x342"));
            BitmapImage poster_400x570 = ImageFromRelativePath(this, con.GetNamedString("poster_400x570"));
            list.Items.Add(new Result {Id=id,Title=title,Themoviedb=themoviedb,Original_title=original_title,Alternate_titles=name,
               Imdb=imdb,Pre_order=pre_order,In_theaters=in_theaters,Release_date=release_date,
               Rating=rating, Rottentomatoes=rottentomatoes,Freebase=freebase,Wikipedia_id=wikipedia_id,

                Common_sense_media = common_sense_media,
                Metacritic= metacritic,
                Poster = Poster_120x171, Poster_240x342=poster_240x342,Poster_400x570=poster_400x570});


        }

    }
}
}
```

my xaml code :

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <ListView
        Name="list"
        DataContext="{Binding}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Orientation="Vertical">

                    <Image Source="{Binding Poster}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="id"
                        Text="{Binding Id}" />

                    <TextBlock
                        Name="title"
                        Text="{Binding Title}" />

                    <TextBlock
                        Name="release_year"
                        Text="{Binding Release_year}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="themoviedb"
                        Text="{Binding Themoviedb}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="original_title"
                        Text="{Binding Original_title}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="alternate_titles"
                        Text="{Binding Alternate_titles}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="imdb"
                        Text="{Binding Imdb}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="pre_order"
                        Text="{Binding Pre_order}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="in_theaters"
                        Text="{Binding In_theaters}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="release_date"
                        Text="{Binding Release_date}" />
                    <HyperlinkButton Content="Common_sense_media" NavigateUri= "{Binding Common_sense_media}"/>
                    <HyperlinkButton Content="metacritic" NavigateUri= "{Binding metacritic}"/>
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="rating"
                        Text="{Binding Rating}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="rottentomatoes"
                        Text="{Binding Rottentomatoes}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="freebase"
                        Text="{Binding Freebase}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="wikipedia_id"
                        Text="{Binding Wikipedia_id}" />

                    <TextBlock
                        Name="common_sense_media"
                        Text="{Binding Common_sense_media}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="poster_120x171"
                        Text="{Binding Poster_120x171}" />
                    <Image Source="{Binding Poster_240x342}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Poster_400x570}" Width="100" Height="100"/>





                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>



</Grid>
```

Comment: Please post your viewmodel code. or atleast property declaration part. Are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: this all my code @LovetoCode please check with me and tell me what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `common_sense_media` value you got contains additional double quotation marks in the start and end like `"\"https://www.commonsensemedia.org/movie-reviews/magic-mike\""`. So you should remove them by using `Trim`, change code as follows

```
string common_sense_media = con.GetNamedValue("common_sense_media").ToString().TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"');
string metacritic = con.GetNamedValue("metacritic").ToString().TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"');
```

Some links still cannot access after this updated, this because the return result of your httprequest for `common_sense_media` and `metacritic` are null. For this situation please deal them with as what you want . You can simple judge

```
if(common_sense_media==null || metacritic==null)
{
  //Do what you want do deal with them, such as give a default link  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The given string to HyperLinkButton was not in proper URL format. Double quote( `""` ) was adding in each end of the string. So if you had noticed you are getting BindingExpressionError(`Error: Converter failed to convert value of type 'Windows.Foundation.String' to type 'Uri'; BindingExpression: Path='Common_sense_media' DataItem='test1.Result, test1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.HyperlinkButton' (Name='null'); target property is 'NavigateUri' (type 'Uri').` )

Use Newtonsoft.Json package for JSON parsing. It has JsonPropertyAttribute which allows you to specify name of Json property, Instructs the Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer to always serialize the member with the specified name. Here is a link for [tutorial](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationattributes.htm). You have to just add `[JsonProperty(keyname)]` to all properties. Library will deserialse json to you
with just one line of code  `Result resu = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(con.ToString())`

Here is the simplified paring code

```
      public class Result
            {
                //public string Alternate_titles { get; set; }
                //public string Common_sense_media { get; set; }
                //public string Freebase { get; set; }
                //public string Id { get; set; }
                //public string Imdb { get; set; }
                //public string In_theaters { get; set; }
                //public string Metacritic { get; set; }
                //public string Original_title { get; set; }
                //public BitmapImage Poster { get; set; }
                //public BitmapImage Poster_240x342 { get; set; }
                //public BitmapImage Poster_400x570 { get; set; }
                //public string Pre_order { get; set; }
                //public string Rating { get; set; }
                //public string Release_date { get; set; }
                //public string Rottentomatoes { get; set; }
                //public string Themoviedb { get; set; }
                //public string Title { get; set; }
                //public string Wikipedia_id { get; set; }
    //declare all above properties like below using JsonProperty
                [JsonProperty("common_sense_media")]
                public string Common_sense_media
                {
                    get; set;

                }
          [JsonProperty("poster_120x171")]
         public string Poster { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("poster_240x342")]
        public string Poster_240x342 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("poster_400x570")]
        public string Poster_400x570 { get; set; }
            }


    public async void jsonCall()
            {
                List<Result> listResult = new List<Result>();

                var client = new HttpClient();
                String jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://api-public.guidebox.com/v1.43/Tunisia/rKgEWJbFg0kgEHrcGXPKhPDo0XtTafyC/movies/all/250/250"));
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(JsonValue.Parse(jsonString).ValueType);
                JsonObject root = JsonValue.Parse(jsonString).GetObject();
                JsonArray res = root.GetNamedArray("results");

                for (uint i = 0; i < res.Count; i++)
                {
                   JsonObject con = res.GetObjectAt(i);
                    Result resu =         Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(con.ToString());
                          list.Items.Add(resu);
                }
         }
```